# Should all HTTP error responses have the same JSON structure?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, error-handling

We are developing a REST service with Spring Boot and got stuck wondering if every error response should have the same JSON structure?

For error cases our service responds with a simple JSON format. For example, if a parameter is malformed we respond with HTTP status `400` and a JSON:

```
{
  "errorCode": 05,
  "message": "provided paramter XY is malformed"
}
```

The `errorCode` is our custom code id. One may argue whether this design is good or not, but it is simple and can be easily handled by the service consumer.

Now, Spring Boot creates some error responses automatically. For example, for a `TypeMismatchException` and response with HTTP status `400` is created. But of course, these automatically generated responses do not have the error format.

So... we have the situation that the service consumer does a prior not know for a HTTP status `400` whether it has the simple JSON error format in the body or not. Should we really overwrite all Spring Boot default exception handling to put our format in each response or should the service consumer swallow the bitter pill and identify if the simple JSON format is used or not?

Comment: They have different structures. Please take a look at my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56135588/how-to-change-response-json-returned-corresponding-to-notnull-annotation/56135933#56135933)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the scale of your project. If your API is used by many applications you should go for the "catch everything and use the JSON format"-approach. Yes you would have more to do but when every other application in your company can use your standard way, they can save a lot of time.

In most of the projects where i was involved, we also had a "standard-way" to give our error-responses back (also JSON):

```
@RestControllerAdvice
public class GlobalResourceExceptionHandler {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GlobalResourceExceptionHandler.class);

    // the class ValidationError contains the properties the json should contain.
    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public List<ValidationError> exceptionHandler(Exception e, HttpServletResponse response) {
        LOGGER.warn("Exception thrown in a resource", e);
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        return Collections.singletonList(new ValidationError(null, "unexpected exception"));
    }
}
```

You can extend the class with more `@ExceptionHandler`s.

It turned out that this is a pretty good way because it is easy to implement (also for small applications) and it covers a lot. A lot means basically everything which had to do with a rest-request. Excluded from this was a resource-handler, which provided an angular-app and the security-layer.

UPDATE:
Conclusion: Catch everything when you have an api used by many applications. You should use the way shown above to start your error-handling in both cases (small or big app).